# Python: Element is trying to be found before it can be

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a project that requires getting mutiple elements matching a class name and looping over them to get the text from each element and print it to the screen the problem is that the code repeats again and get's the last question until i kill the script i took a look at the code and noticed the element i was trying to use is always clickable so i removed that code and decided to try and catch the text related to the last text which is FINISH i took a look and found the ID and built the code below however the problem is that it attempts to find the element before it get's to the last question a possible solution is also attached

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    Firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
    Firefox.get('ThisIsAExampleWebsite.com')
    # Not the actual website
    # Website isn't included since it's a local business
    Username = 
    Firefox.find_element_by_id('Username_Login').send_keys('Test')
    Password = 
    Firefox.find_element_by_id('Password_Login').send_keys('Test')
    # Not actual username/password
    Article = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Article').click()
    Get_Text = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Article_Text').click()
    while True:
        Article_Texts = Firefox.find_elements_by_id('All_Text')
        for Text in Article_Texts:
            print(Article_Texts.text)
        try:
            Finish = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Finish')
            print('  Done  ' )
            break
        except:
            print('  Not Done ' )
            continue
```

Edit: I have looked into replacing the while loop with a for loop using the element that is each part of the article if i use find_elements on this class name and get the size using len() code is below

```
Length_Text = len(Firefox.find_elements_by_class_name('NextText'))
for I in range(0, Length_Text):
    Article_Text = Firefox.find_elements_by_id('All_Text')
    for Text in Article_Text:
       print(Text.text)
```

The idea behind this is if i only loop the code for how many next text there are then it won't loop the last text but this code still loops it any idea why?

Comment: Please make sure your indentation is correct!

Comment: I've turned your code into a code block. Please [edit] your question to make sure it does have the proper syntax /indentation of your actual code.

Comment: Please look at my post i pointed out that i can't figure out how to indent on a phone on Stack Overflow my bad i pointed out the syntax is wrong here due to that

Comment: Please check whether the current guess at indentation matches your actual code. Since this code is not complete/runnable, please clarify what it is supposed to do (Which part looks for the question? Where should it break?) and what it does instead (Does it throw an Exception? If so, where and what is the traceback? Otherwise, how does it break the loop). See the [ask] and [mcve] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: I wrote this by hand on my mobile device the code has the proper syntax on my laptop please read my question where i state that Stack Overflow messed up my code syntax

Comment: There isn't much we can do without knowing your code. If you currently cannot provide the correct code, please do so when you can. Be aware that your question is automatically queued for reopen review when it is edited again.

Comment: I have tried saying my code is correct it's just the syntax isn't correct on Stack Overflow the code is correct it's just the syntax here i am on mobile device i have tried spacing the code with the proper syntax however Stack Overflow goes to a new line so i can't I'm trying to print the question until there isn't anymore questions left i have tried getting this to work but it checks for the element before it get's to the last question

Comment: I fixed the code I'l add a possible solution if the question get's reopened no point in doing it until that happens